# Swift: Images placed in a tableviewcell are not visible

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "approve_cell");
  let event = self.events[indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel?.text = event.name;
  return cell;
 }
```

I placed 2 images and a label in tableviewcell. When i run the app, images are not visible. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creat cell in storyboard but you never use this cell created from storyboard. instead you manually creat it by UITableViewCell's designated initializer without override layout method of it.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "approve_cell", for: indexPath)

  let event = self.events[indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel?.text = event.name;
  return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are not using the basic style of the `UITableViewCell` because if you are then that style only includes labels.. no image views. Change it to subtitle or one of the details.

For reference, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: i am using custom

Comment: Ok, can you check your constraints?

Comment: Why are you creating a new cell each time instead of dequeueing it? @MihirThanekar is correct. In cellForRow method you are returning a cell with default style not custom.

Comment: in properties inspector i selected custom as Style

Comment: what is dequeueing?

Comment: It means instead of creating a new instance of UITableViewCell you reuse a cell you already have. This is the way apple can save memory in your table view. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to set AutoLayoutConstraints of your image view. You could either add constraints to that image view through storyboard or through code. The other method is setting the frame of your image view in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because when you're using auto-layout, the layout of those views will be undefined if its constraints doesn't fulfill system's computing need. So you should either set right constraints or give a specific frame to those undefined views after all of the others has-constraints-views are arranged.

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry! I didn't see your constraints picture at the first time. I think I know why your image view can't be showed by now. Since you just pin your image view's top and bottom but you didn't handle its width, the check and delete image views' width should be zero at runtime. Please either pin imageViews' left to a proper position and specify their width, or pin their left and right to a proper position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set either Autolayout or used Autoresizing. For autolayout just pinned the proper leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint.